# how to get next non empty cell value in an excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my excel looks

```
Column A        Column B
1/1/2016          
2/1/2016
3/1/2016
4/1/2016
5/1/2016
.
.
.
31/1/2016          1000
```

Now I will be referring one of the date in this month on another sheet and I would like to pull Column B value corresponding to last date on each month. There wont be any value till last date on column B.

Any hint to do this ?

Comment: You could look at the EOMONTH function in conjunction with either VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** step is to make the condition:

```
=IF(A1=EOMONTH(A1,0),B1,"")
```

Note: if date in A1 is really the end of its month, it takes result from B1

**Second** step is to combine it with Vlookup. I assume that you would input some date in column C:

```
=IF(C1=EOMONTH(A1,0),VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$1000,2,FALSE),"")
```

**Third** step is... you can change the formula if your input is in another sheet. For the example: *the data are in "sheet1" and the date input are in column C at "sheet2"*:

```
=IF(C1=EOMONTH(Sheet1!A1,0),VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1000,2,FALSE),"")
```

Hope it'll help.